# Queries related to JIRA-Scripted Field

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

Is scripted field appear on ISSUE EDIT or any transition screen?

For me, it appear on issue view screen only and unable to see on issue edit screen.

I want it to appear on EDIT screen as well as a readonly.

(have verified by just keeping - "free text template" and - return "some value").

Another:

When I have use below script on scripted field then it shows me error while execute:

> Error message as below:
>   The indexer for this field expects a java.lang.String but
>   the script returned a `com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomFieldImpl` - this will cause problems.

Code:

```
  import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager.  
  import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField 
  import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager 
  CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = componentManager.getCustomFieldManager() 
  def componentManager = ComponentManager.getInstance() 
  def issueLinkManager = componentManager.getIssueLinkManager()  
  def selectedValues = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_11447")
  //custom field has multi selected values as it is a "multi select" field type. 
  return selectedValues
```

How I could use scripted field in issue edit/transition screen and also resolve above error.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, no a scripted field wont be displayed on a Create, Edit or Transition screen. There is a work around for transition screens but I have not tried it https://gist.github.com/jechlin/5380119

Now the second part of your question. You are returning an object of CustomeField and you should be returning a String. What you want to do is

change this

```
def selectedValues = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_11447")
```

to this

```
def cf = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_11447")
def selectedValues = cf.getValue(issue)
```

Here is a link to the api documentation for JIRA (6.0.4):
https://developer.atlassian.com/static/javadoc/jira/6.0.4/reference/packages.html

Comment: I cant add more links but here is a link to the Scripted Fields documentation: [link](https://jamieechlin.atlassian.net/wiki/display/GRV/Scripted+Fields)

Comment: Many thanks. can you please suggest any other approach through jquery/javascript which allows me to create such duplicate field and it could also appear on EDIT screen ? basically, requirement is just have a review screen and EDIT issue screen (review tab) where match the EXPECTED and ACTUAL field) so, EXPECTED field is the duplicate of existing field.